# Accessing HttpOnly cookies across multiple domain with URL redirection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-3.1, httpcookie, cookie-httponly

I have an ASP.Net MCV website (.net 4.6) (**https://site.aa.main.com**) and we have built a redirection to an Angular SAP (**https://spa.aa.new.main.com**). We also have a standalone API (.net core 3.1)(**https://api.aa.new.main.com:5001**) to serve requests from the SPA.

Here I need to set a cookie in site 1 before the redirection, then I can use that cookie in the API.

I have the below code in site 1 to set this cookie,

```
HttpCookie payidCookie = new HttpCookie("myKey", "myValue")
{
     Secure = true,
     HttpOnly = true,             
     Domain = ".new.main.com",
};

this.Response.Cookies.Add(payidCookie);
```

Then I have the below code to consume the cookie in the API,

```
if (Request.Cookies["myKey"] != null)
{
    var value = Request.Cookies["myKey"];
}
```

But the cookie is not available in the API. Request.Cookies["myKey"] return null.

Does anyone know why I cannot see the cookie in the API and how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case is explicitly covered in specification, `site.aa.main.com` [cannot](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3) set cookies for `new.main.com`:

> The user agent will reject cookies unless the Domain attribute
> specifies a scope for the cookie that would include the origin
> server.  For example, the user agent will accept a cookie with a
> Domain attribute of "example.com" or of "foo.example.com" from
> foo.example.com, but the user agent will not accept a cookie with a
> Domain attribute of "bar.example.com" or of "baz.foo.example.com".

You would either have to set cookie for `main.com` or figure out other naming setup that would have common subdomain for all involved hosts.